# noConflict breaks my existing JavaScript

Tags: jquery, prestashop

I can't figure out how to configure jQuery NoConflict().

This small function (jquery) works fine:

```
    $('.product_list > li').css('width', '50%').css('width', '-=42px');
    $('.product_grid > li').css('width', '20%').css('width', '-=42px');
    $('.product_grid ul.buttons li').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=21px');
```

It stops working when I run another jQuery script.

This is a "blocklayered.js" and it also uses some AJAX script (this si a script that works for filtering products in prestashop)

How can I to use `noConflict`?

I tried this by creating a new *.js file and adding it right after the jQuery library:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.product_list > li').css('width', '50%').css('width', '-=42px');
        jQuery('.product_grid > li').css('width', '20%').css('width', '-=42px');
        jQuery('.product_grid ul.buttons li').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=21px');
});
```

This method made all my jQuery functions stop working.

The way console says this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

**I want to mention:**

that when the blocklayered.js/AJAX is runing all other jquery function works fine, as before, the only problem is with this function:

```
    $('.product_list > li').css('width', '50%').css('width', '-=42px');
$('.product_grid > li').css('width', '20%').css('width', '-=42px');
$('.product_grid ul.buttons li').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=21px');
```

Comment: Please update your post to include the order of JS references in your page.

Comment: What's the stacktrace of that TypeError? It's possible that you're using `$` somewhere else than in the code you've shown us.

Comment: What do you expect `noConflict()` to do? Seems like you think it should do something else then it actually does.

Comment: replaced jQuery.noConflict(); with $.noConflict(); no result!

Comment: `noConflict` is for when you have 2 (or more) version of jQuery on the same page.

Comment: That's one use case, but not the only one.

Comment: @RocketHazmat more often different JS libraries using `$` as shorthand.

Comment: @JakubMichálek: Yes, that too.  You're right.

Comment: What does "another jQuery script" mean?  Is that another copy of jQuery, or just another script that happens to use jQuery.  Why do you think you need `noConflict`?  You might not actually need it.

Comment: Ok, lets say "$" makes problem, so if I replace it somthing esle, its possible by using VAR, then why still not working?